# If $ap(x)\leq q(x)\leq bp(x)$ then $p,q$ are equivalent

Tags: normed-spaces

I'm having some trouble proving the following proposition:

> Let $p$ and $q$ be two norms over the same space $E$. Then, if there are positive real numbers $a,b$ such that, for all $x\in E$:$$ap(x)\leq q(x)\leq bp(x)$$
> the norms $p,q$ are equivalent

Proving that $p,q$ are equivalent is the same as proving that $$Id:(E,p)\to(E,q)$$ is a homeomorphism, so that's exactly what I tried to do, but I wasn't able to use the inequality.
How can this be done?

Comment: The identity map is obviously a bijection, so you just need to show it's continuous.  To simplify, can you show that it is continuous at 0? Then try to reduce the generic case to this specific one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT.- First at all, the field of scalars is $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$.

You do have $q(x)\le bp(x)$ and $p(x)\le \dfrac 1a q(x)$ which means the the linear function identity is continuous from $(E,p)$ to $(E,q)$ and from $(E,q)$ to $(E,p)$ respectively. In other words that all open in $(E,p)$ is open in $(E,q)$ and reciprocally, so the same topology, so equivalent norms.